# Scrapy time out when doing braod search

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to get all the music file types out of the copyright.gov website for the last 3 years using scrapy however I keep getting this error:

```
User timeout caused connection failure: Getting http://cocatalog.loc.gov/cgi-bin/Pwebrecon.cgi?PID=JADxIm18gK9YX6t-BSYC9oABskwhR&SEQ=20150331032850&CNT=25&HIST=1&Search_Arg=PAu003%3F&Search_Code=FT%2A took longer than 180 seconds..
```

I know its some restriction on the site (even doing manual search causes the website to time out. Here is my spider:

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from datetime import datetime
from scrapy.http import FormRequest, Request
from scrapy.utils.response import open_in_browser


class CopyrightSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "copyright_records"
    start_urls = ["http://cocatalog.loc.gov/cgi-bin/Pwebrecon.cgi?DB=local&PAGE=First"]

    def parse(self, response):
            yield FormRequest.from_response(response,
                                            formname='querybox',
                                            formdata={'Search_Arg': 'music?',  'Search_Code': 'FT*'},
                                            cookies={'s_sess':'%20s_cc%3Dtrue%3B%20s_sq%3D%3B', 's_vi':'[CS]v1|2A8CD884851D46DB-400019054027B53D[CE]'},
                                            callback=self.parse1)



    def parse1(self, response):

        open_in_browser(response)
```

Is there any way around this time out problem?

Comment: use 'DOWNLOAD_DELAY' & 'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS'.

Answer (score 0):

Set DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT in your settings.py, be default its value is 180 seconds

```
    DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT = 360 // for six minutes.
```